# Why 505 Http Version Not Supported on public WiFi?

Tags: http, azure, https, azure-storage

I've been getting a 505 'Http Version Not Support' whilst trying to access Azure storage recently. It took me a while to figure out that it was only happening on public WiFi (e.g. First Great Western, Tesco etc). The fix was simple: edit my storage connection string to use https i.e. DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;

However, here's my question: why did this only occur on public WiFi? http was accepted by Azure when I was tethered to my mobile or used my home WiFi connection. Fiddler didn't show any difference in the requests sent from my machine, so what are these hotspots doing to http traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the problem is because of a network proxy being used by the public WiFi provider. There are known bugs in the Squid 2.x series, for example, which may be converting HTTP 1.1 requests to HTTP 1.0. We had a similar problem with talking to Azure through a Squid proxy.

Your workaround of switching to HTTPS is the recommended one.